# c# How to determine size of group in Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string and i want extract the fist word in one group, and the rest in antoher group :

Ex :

String : String Example for stack

Group 1 : String
Group 2 : Example for stack

I tried this pattern

(\w+)\s

But, he get only 2 words

[image: Regex Test]

Comment: `(\w+)\s([\w\s]*)` ...

Comment: worked... thanks a lot... i really appreciated

Comment: What if there is only one word? Or later some punctuation? Use `^(\w+)(?:\s*(.*))?$`. Also, the screen comes from regexr that does not support .NET regex syntax. Test at regexstorm.net or regexhero.net.